# VHDL - Input not used

Tags: vhdl

I have problem with this piece of code, "s" doesn't appear in "Floorplan I/O pins" because it is never used why?  How could I solve this problem?

```
entity tempModule is
  port (s  : in  std_logic;
        ss : out std_logic);
end tempModule;

architecture tempModule_Behavioral of tempModule is
begin
  process(s)
  begin
    if (s = '1') then
      ss <= '1';
    end if;
  end process;
end tempModule_Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that pin s and ss are in your UCF?

One thing you could try would be to just do:

```
ss <= s;
```

That would ensure that it would not be optimized away.

Answer (score 2):

The VHDL design describes a module that drives `'U'` (Uninitialized) on output
`ss` from power up and until input `s` is `'1'`, and then output `ss` is `'1'`
from then on.

Since the `'U'` (Uninitialized) value output in the beginning on `ss` can be
implemented as any value by the simulation tool, it may be implemented as
`'1'`, whereby the output `ss` is just trivial `'1'`, and the input `s` is
thereby unused.

So it sounds like the synthesis tool behaviour is as can be expected, but maybe
the module behavior is to be modified, since the modules does not appear to do
anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

You are implementing a COMBINATIONAL circuit, so the COMPLETE truth table must be described.

However, you have only specified ss for s='1', thus the compiler understands that it is OK to simply keep the output high all the time, in which case s is not actually needed.

To specify ss for all possible values of s, try to end your if statement with "else", like this:

```
if ...;
elsif ...;
else ...;
```